# Library system manager

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I'm new to JavaScript OOP and still playing around with it. I have put together a few specific questions over specific details throughout the code that are bothering me.

I wanted my `Library` class constructor to be optional, the option to add a single book, multiple books or none at all, when creating the  object. Is this a good way of achieving this goal?

```
class Library{
  constructor(items){
    this.books = [];
    if(typeof items != 'undefined' && items instanceof Array){
      this.books.push.apply(this.books, items); // Concat two arrays
    } else if(typeof items != 'undefined') {
      this.books.push(items); // Add one element
    }
  }

  checkIn(id, renter){
    var index = this.getIndex(id);
    if(!this.books[index].available){
      this.books[index].setDefaults();
      renter.removeBook(id);
    } else {
      throw "Book Already Checked In";
    }
  }

  checkOut(id, renter){
    var index = this.getIndex(id);
    if(this.books[index].available){
      this.books[index].available = false;
      this.books[index].currentRenter = renter.name;

      // Adds current date to check out information.
      var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
      this.books[index].checkOutDate = dateFormat(new Date(),  "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");

      renter.addBook(this.books[index]); // Adds book to renter's inventory.
    } else {
      throw "Book Not Available";
    }
  }

  getIndex(id){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.books.length; i++){
      if(this.books[i].id == id) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

My `Book` class works, but just does not feel correct at all and looks very sloppy. Any thoughts?

```
class Book{
  constructor(title, pageCount, id){
    this.title = title;
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
    this.id = id;
    this.available = true;
    this.currentRenter = null;
    this.checkOutDate = null;
  }

  setDefaults(){
    this.available = true;
    this.currentRenter = null;
    this.checkOutDate = null;
  }
}
```

These are the only classes I did not really have any questions over. I am aware splitting these classes into two is completely unnecessary in this scenario, but I was just messing around with inheritance and never changed it back.

```
class Person{
  constructor(name, age, phoneNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }
}

class Renter extends Person{
  constructor(name, age, phoneNumber, libraryID){
    super(name, age, phoneNumber)
    this.libraryID = libraryID;
    this.books = [];
  }

  addBook(book){
    this.books.push(book);
  }

  removeBook(id){
    var index = this.getIndex(id);
    this.books.splice(index, 1);
  }

  getIndex(id){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.books.length; i++){
      if(this.books[i].id == id) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Another general question: Am I accessing the class variables "formally"? It does not feel right setting a instance variable without a setter or returning a instance variable without a getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkIn(id, renter){...}
checkOut(id, renter){...}
```

You're not actually checking in the `id` of a book. You're checking in *a book*. So I would suggest accepting an instance of a book and get the ID from it instead of passing in an ID. You're already doing it for `renter`, passing in the renter instance, so it shouldn't be different.

```
this.books = [];
```

I would suggest using an object `{}` instead of an array. One problem with using an array, and the ID as index is that you unknowingly increase the `length` of the array. If you check the length of an empty array after doing `this.books[100] = new Book(...)`, you'll see that it's `101`. The array stretched to 101 elements and left gaps in between.

If the book is checked out, you can either `null` its entry in the object or delete it altogether with `delete`. It also makes `getIndex` unnecessary as you can simply access the object directly with `id` as key.

```
throw "Book Already Checked In";
```

I would suggest throwing an instance of `Error` instead of a string. Error-catching code will most likely expect an instance of `Error` and not a string. You also lose out on extra information that comes with an instance of `Error`. Lastly, not OOP-ish. :P

```
checkOut(id, renter){
  ...
  var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
```

Dependencies should be done outside anything. Behavior depends on the loader used. If you used RequireJS this would try to resolve `dateformat`, and load it on the fly. Other module loaders may inline the code, causing this function to bloat.

```
this.currentRenter = null;
this.checkOutDate = null;
```

The book shouldn't be aware of its renter. All it should be describing is the book itself.

If you want something like a library card, then I suggest making a property `libraryCard` that holds an array of `LibraryCardRecord` objects, each containing the date of checkout and the id of the renter at that date.

> It does not feel right setting a instance variable without a setter or returning a instance variable without a getter.

It's overkill, but it's a good practice to always use a getter and setter. While it's meaningless in the world of all-public JavaScript, it allows you to do intermediate operations before setting or getting. ES6 does have special syntax for [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted my Library class constructor to be optional, the option to add a single book, multiple books or none at all

Yes this is possible using the `arguments` object in Javascript

```js
   

 class Library{
      constructor(){
        this.books = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);                            
        console.log(this.books);
        console.log(arguments.length);
      }
    }
         var library2 = new Library(new Array("Saab", "45", 2),new Array("Saab2", 56, 7));
```

Note : Implementing this will require a `for(){}` to be able to add as much books you require.

// So you can add as much arguments has you need

> ```js
>     var library1 = new Library(new Array("Saab", "45", 2));
>
>     var library2 = new Library(new Array("Saab", "45", 2),new Array("Saab2", 56, 7));
>
>     var library3 = new Library();
> ```

- As you clearly stated this is an OOP structure, then your `Library` should be taking a `BOOK` object as an argument has opposed to you creating an `Array` called `this.books` to contain all the arguments passed because passing the `Book` class requires you to fill in `title`, `pageCount`, `id` For instance

```js
 var library2 = new Library(new Book("Saab", "45", 2),new Book("Saab2", 56, 7));
```

- Javascript is a loose language. Note, it's a bit wierd for instance you would expect when you declared `available`, `currentReader` and `checkOutdate` variables the scope was limited to `setdefaults()` and hence you repeated this variables in the `constructor`. The truth is the `Book` class has access to it because you used `this`. So you can do the below . This will avoid **DRY**(**D**ont **R**epeat **Y**ourself)

```js
class Book{
  constructor(title, pageCount, id){
    this.title = title;
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
    this.id = id;
    this.setDefaults();
  }
 setDefaults(){
    this.available = true;
    this.currentRenter = null;
    this.checkOutDate = null;
  }
}

var book = new Book('Pokemon', 23, 1);
console.log(book.available);
```

- Just for clarity sake, I would have this line at the top before calling defining the classes 
   
  `var dateFormat = require('dateformat');`

As @Joseph the Dreamer suggested your `checkIn` and `checkOut` can be improved on as their names differ from their functionalities .
I hope this helps. Cheers